# Bitbucket Server - Get Builds

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Does anybody know if there is a way to get a list of Builds from the Bitbucket Server via the API?

I am looking for something similar to the [List pipelines](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pipelines/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pipelines-get) endpoint for the Bitbucket Cloud. But i need to get a list of Builds from the Bitbucket Server